# How create a freestyle jenkins job which is running in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a simple c++ to compile and run using jenkins freestyle job it is working fine if I use  jenkins built in my OS (Linux mint tricia) commands I use:

```
cd "destination"
g++ main.cpp -o test
./test
```

everything is working good.
BUT,now I m running jenkins from docker container and when I try to do this I get error `cant cd to "destination"`, I know this is because docker is isolated from host machine, So I want to ask how could I make a simple freestyle job which executes programs which is on my host machine using jenkins which is running inside docker?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Just run your jenknis container with volume like `docker run -it -v destination:destination jenkins`